# Firebase phone authentication never works

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a flutter app where the user needs to authenticate using his phone number. For that I am using Firebase Auth, but it never works, I always get the following errors:

```
E/zzf     ( 7997): Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
I/zzmh    ( 7997): Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
W/System  ( 7997): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth( 7997): [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with INVALID_CERT_HASH 400
E/zzf     ( 7997): Failed to get reCAPTCHA token with error [There was an error while trying to get your package certificate hash.]- calling backend without app verification
W/System  ( 7997): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
E/FirebaseAuth( 7997): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17006 null
I/flutter ( 7997): operation-not-allowed
```

I have already done the following:

- Added the SHA-1 and SHA-256 in my Firebase settings;
- Activated the Android Device Verification for my project;
- Activated the Smartphone sign-in method;
- Activated the SafetyNet in Firebase App Check;
- Updated the google-services.json several times
- Added implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0' to build.gradle

None of these solved my problem. Does anybody know how to make the smartphone authentication work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran "fluter clean" and it worked

Comment: Hi I already implemented Play integrity API and App Safe tried multiple times flutter clean and all solution but still facing ReCaptcha on android.